# AWS Hosted Parse-server can't find cloud code

Tags: amazon-web-services, parse-server

We are in the process of migrating from parse.com to AWS.
The solution works perfectly fine locally, however once i `eb deploy` to AWS, it cannot load the cloud code file.

```
Error: Cannot find module '/cloud/main.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:325:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:276:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
    at new ParseServer (/var/app/current/node_modules/parse-server/lib/ParseServer.js:268:9)
    at new _ParseServer (/var/app/current/node_modules/parse-server/lib/index.js:38:16)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/app/current/index.js:8:11)
    at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
```

My parse server config looks like this:

```
var api = new ParseServer({
    databaseURI: config.DATABASE_URI ,
    cloud:  __dirname + '/cloud/main.js' ,
    appId: config.parse.APP_ID,
    masterKey: config.parse.MASTER_KEY ,
    restApiKey: config.parse.REST_API_KEY,
    serverURL: config.parse.SERVER_URL   // Don't forget to change to https if needed
});
```

AWS obviously cant find the file @ `__dirname + '/cloud/main.js'` 
What should i set this to for AWS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I just removed the leading `/` and now it works.

It now reads `cloud:  'cloud/main.js' ,`